# Round robin with record limitation

Tags: oracle, sequence, hql, analytics, round-robin

I have to build a hive SQL query for the following requirement

I have an customer table. I need to divide the total table record by 6 (i.e suppose table contain 600 records each month 100 record upto 6 month), each month there is an bracket to target a customer. suppose the bracket limit is 4 then I need to pick 5 unique email id from 5 unique account. incase 10 then 10 unique email id from 10 unique account

Note: I am using mod operation to distribute the record for 6 month.

| Account | Email | Mod,6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc 1 | email@acc1 | 1 |
| acc2 | email1@acc2 | 1 |
| acc2 | email2@acc2 | 2 |
| acc2 | email3@acc2 | 3 |
| acc2 | email4@acc2 | 4 |
| acc2 | email5@acc2 | 5 |
| acc2 | email6@acc2 | 6 |
| acc2 | email7@acc2 | 1 |
| acc3 | email1@acc3 | 1 |
| acc3 | email2@acc3 | 2 |
| acc3 | email3@acc3 | 3 |
| acc4 | email@acc4 | 1 |
| acc5 | email1@acc5 | 1 |
| acc5 | email2@acc5 | 2 |

Expected output - Bracket is 4 ( below output acc5 is not required as the record count already reached bracket range-4)

| Account | Email | mod,6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc 1 | email@acc1 | 1 |
| acc2 | email1@acc2 | 1 |
| acc3 | email1@acc3 | 1 |
| acc4 | email@acc4 | 1 |

if Bracket is 8 ( I have to pick the all the unique account first and then other sequence to reach the bracket range )

Expected output

| Account | Email | mod,6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc 1 | email@acc1 | 1 |
| acc2 | email1@acc2 | 1 |
| acc3 | email1@acc3 | 1 |
| acc4 | email@acc4 | 1 |
| acc5 | email1@acc5 | 1 |
| acc2 | email7@acc2 | 1 |
| acc2 | email2@acc2 | 2 |
| acc3 | email2@acc3 | 2 |

if Bracket is 10

| Account | Email | mod,6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc 1 | email@acc1 | 1 |
| acc2 | email1@acc2 | 1 |
| acc3 | email1@acc3 | 1 |
| acc4 | email@acc4 | 1 |
| acc5 | email1@acc5 | 1 |
| acc2 | email7@acc2 | 1 |
| acc2 | email2@acc2 | 2 |
| acc3 | email2@acc3 | 2 |
| acc5 | email2@acc5 | 2 |
| acc2 | email3@acc2 | 3 |

I tried below query. But it fetch all the 1 record first. I am not sure how to fetch unique account record with mod_seq_value 1 first and then start the remain records from the mod seq -1.

```
select * from (
select *, Row_number() over(order by mod_num_seq,acc_count) as rnk
select account,email,
count(*) over(partition by account) as acc_count
,case 
when mod(row_number() over(partition by account),6)=0 then 6
else mod(row_number() over(partition by account),6)=0 
end as mod_num_seq
from 
customer
)a
)b where rnk<={:bracket}
```

Comment: What is MOD,6 based on? Is it based on an ID or similar? (show this in your sample data) Are you looking to find a way to randomize the chosen emails? It's not entirely clear to me what you really want.

Comment: It's the NTILE() function that could help you, with the drawback it requires an expression as parameter (NOT as statement) so you will have to calculate it before and pass as parameter.

Comment: Mod - 6 is based on the Row number -  mod(row_number() over(partition by account),6). My requirement is to bring at least one email ID from each account. There are some accounts that contain multiple email IDs. so I am using a mod operation. In a round-robin way first, I need to pull mod value - 1 record and then 2 & so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why 6th and 7th row in your output are `email7@acc2, email2@acc2` instead of `email7@acc2, email2@acc3`.

```
with customer (account, email, x) as
(
select 'acc1','email@acc1', 1 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email1@acc2',  1 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email2@acc2',  2 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email3@acc2',  3 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email4@acc2',  4 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email5@acc2',  5 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email6@acc2',  6 from dual
union all select 'acc2','email7@acc2',  1 from dual
union all select 'acc3','email1@acc3',  1 from dual
union all select 'acc3','email2@acc3',  2 from dual
union all select 'acc3','email3@acc3',  3 from dual
union all select 'acc4','email@acc4',   1 from dual
union all select 'acc5','email1@acc5',  1 from dual
union all select 'acc5','email2@acc5',  2 from dual
)
, t as 
(
select c.*, mod(row_number() over (partition by account order by email) - 1, 6) + 1 rn
from customer c
)
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by account order by rn, email) pick_up_order
from t
order by pick_up_order, account;
```

Result:

```
ACCOUNT EMAIL                X         RN PICK_UP_ORDER
------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -------------
acc1    email@acc1           1          1             1
acc2    email1@acc2          1          1             1
acc3    email1@acc3          1          1             1
acc4    email@acc4           1          1             1
acc5    email1@acc5          1          1             1
acc2    email7@acc2          1          1             2
acc3    email2@acc3          2          2             2
acc5    email2@acc5          2          2             2
acc2    email2@acc2          2          2             3
acc3    email3@acc3          3          3             3
acc2    email3@acc2          3          3             4
acc2    email4@acc2          4          4             5
acc2    email5@acc2          5          5             6
acc2    email6@acc2          6          6             7

14 rows selected.
```